# Maintain context values between routes in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to maintain state values between routes in context. But it gets reset when the route changes.

aackage.json:

```json
 "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
 "react": "^18.2.0",
```

App.js:

```js
export default const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const data = await axios.get("url", {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    setData(data);
    setLoading(false);
  };

   useEffect(() => {
    getData()
    console.log("I run on route change");
  }, []);
  

  const GlobalContextValue= {
    data: data,
    loading: loading,
  };



   return (
    <>
      <GlobalContextProvider value={GlobalContextValue}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/:slug" element={<PostPage />} />
          {/* <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} /> */}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </<GlobalContextProvider />
    </>
  )

}
```

Whenever I try to access any route the **getData** function inside the useEffect calls which inturns resets the data. I have attached a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-cherry-qklq5p?file=/src/App.js:469-742) to replicate the same

I don't know if this problem is related to reactJs or react-router. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to setup a store like react-redux. and then you can share data accross components and routes and so on.

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the code you've shared, so it's unclear what issue you are experiencing or any reason(s) why. Please [edit] the post to include better and clearer details about any issues and a set of reproduction steps that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't seem to have any navigation link, I assume you are using the browser search bar, or a normal HTML `<a>` tag. Well, doing so refreshes the page, so the entire app gets re-created.

Using `useNavigate` or `Link` from React Router Dom, doesn't refresh the page, hence your context data remains untouched:

```js
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hii Homepage </h1>
      <Link to="/1">Go to PostPage</Link>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const PostPage = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hii PostPage {params.slug} </h1>
      <Link to="/">Go to HomePage</Link>
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "I run on load and route change with browser search bar, not with useNavigate or Link"
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {/* This context wrapping BrowserRouter keeps its value if you navigate with Link or
      useNavigate. */}
      <GlobalContextProvider value={{ key: "some value" }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/:slug" element={<PostPage />} />
            {/* <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} /> */}
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </GlobalContextProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou it really worked.  I had used <a> tag instead of link tag within the component. Converting it into <Link> solved the issue